# How to expose a generator to ES5 code?

Tags: babeljs

This question is specific to **library** creation. Similar questions have been asked related to tests, but libraries require a different approach because they are consumed independently.

I'm writing a library that exposes a class that is iterable using a generator. It is compiled to ES5 with [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and includes the [polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

How can ES5 code iterate over the generator in a straightforward way?

I'm thinking about adding a `toArray` method to the class that turns the result into an array:

```js
// GeneratorClass is exposed by the library

var generator = new GeneratorClass();

generator.toArray().forEach(function (item) {
  // ...
});
```

Is this a common approach? Or is there a better one?

Even though they are available, you can't expect consumers to know/care about how to use the `generator[Symbol.iterator]` and `iterator.next` methods.

Comment: I'm a  fan of the `.toArray` option since it's so easy to `return Array.from(this)`

Comment: Could you just add a `forEach` method to `GeneratorClass` directly? Saves you from having to construct an array only to iterate it then throw it away.